# How do Hit Dice affect levels and level adjustment?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, character-levels

I'm a DM trying to deal with monster player characters and I don't really understand level adjustment and ECL. I'm trying to understand how Racial Hit Die affect ECL, particularly in reference  to the quote below which I found [here](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?207928-Urpriest-s-Monstrous-Monster-Handbook).

"Effective Character Level, or ECL, is equal to your Racial Hit Dice, plus your Class Levels, plus your Level Adjustment."

Is this just because that's how a monster's level is shown in the Monster Manual? Would I need this to adjust my players monster characters?

Comment: That quote is correct. Can you clarify for us which part of it doesn't make sense to you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/28176/how-exactly-does-a-level-adjustment-work?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How exactly does a level adjustment work?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/28176/how-exactly-does-a-level-adjustment-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's how a monster's level (for the purposes of player characters) is listed.

## Racial Hit Dice

Think of racial hit die as character levels. They both grant base attack bonus, HP, saves, and feats. Racial HD don't grant class features, though - instead, the monster has special attacks and special qualities based on its race.

## Level adjustment

A lot of monsters are really strong, but have relatively few class levels. For example, a [rakshasa](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/rakshasa.htm) has 7 racial hit dice, but it much more powerful than a 7th level character - in addition to sorcerer casting it also has spell resistance, damage reduction, shape-changing, etc. **Level adjustment** is an estimate of how much these "extra" abilities are worth, in terms of levels. So a rakshasa player character would be considered 14th level. It is not possible to play a 13th level rakshasa without introducing some changes to the game.

## Class levels

After you add up Racial Hit Dice and Level Adjustment, the character proceeds as normal. A rakshasa with 1 level of sorcerer is level 15 - 7 RHD, 7 LA, 1 class level.

Comment: Some warning about how poorly this system works and how deleterious LA and (to a somewhat lesser extent) RHD are would improve this answer.

Comment: The question did not ask for an assessment of whether or not listed LA values were balanced.

Answer (score 1):

- **Class levels** are the levels you take in any class, prestige or not (e.g. Cleric, Arcane Archer, etc.). They grant you hit die, skill points, class skills, save throws and hit points.
- **Racial Hit Die** are levels you gain in a "racial class". These levels give you whatever that specific ***monster type*** gets per level (e.g. Dragon, Monstrous Humanoid, etc.).  These levels grant you hit die, skill points, save throws and hit points, ***but usually no class skills***.
- **Level Adjustment** is an added handicap on specially powerful species. These level adjustments give you absolutely nothing, but they add to your final effective level.
- **Effective Character Level** is the sum of the previous three. It is used to set combat difficulties, experience gain, level gain, etc. In essence this is your real 'Level'; any time someone asks you what level your character is, this is what you should say.

So if you have 3 monster hit die, 2 level adjustment and 5 levels in classes (Cleric for example), then your Effective Character Level would be 10. You would need enough XP to get to level 11 in order to gain a new level, and if someone kills you, she would gain xp for killing a level 10 character.

However, in that example you would have 8 hit die, because that 2 Level adjustments don't grant you hit die, and so they grant you no hit points. 8 would be the number to look at to know your maximum skill points in a single skill, and would be the number to look at to see how a spell affects you if it has different effects depending on how many hit die you have.